# How can I move my notes from iCloud folder to GMail folder

Tags: iphone, icloud, gmail, notes.app

Only iCloud folder displays in the move menu. Even though GMail folder is normally present.

Comment: Do you mean Google Drive?

Comment: No, I mean the gmail note syncing in Notes app.

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: I'm using iOS 11.0 @oa-